Citation Feature Request II
It would be nice to have a link on questions/answers that generates a (bibtex) citation. There is a lot of great original content produced on this site, and proper attribution should be made as easy as possible.
This feature was requested before in 2018 (Citation Feature Request) but didn't go through. The feature itself doesn't seem difficult to implement (https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4209/138661).
Examples
Currently, QCSE has this list of options under each answer:

Physics SE and math SE have this the list of options:

CS theory SE has this list of options:

Here is an example of what pops up when you click "Cite"


I don't see any potential downsides, so I'll ask around to see if/when it can be done!

Matter Modeling has the cite feature too.

@TristanNemoz consider retagging this feature request with [meta-tag:status-review] so that the staff is aware of it.

@AndrewT. Even though the post seems well-received and I don't see any downside to this, I'd rather let the post "live" for a tad bit longer, to be sure that if someone does have a counterargument, they at least got a bit of time to express it, especially in this period! (after all, the post has only been seen 24 times ATM). Once that's done, sure!
